# A Lie-like product in rings with involution

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras

Suppose $R$ is a ring with involution $*$ and $x,y\in R$. Does the quantity $xy-y^{*}x^{*}$ have a standard name? Has this product undergone systematic study in the ring-theory literature, and if so, where? (It may be, for fundamental reasons, that this product is not as interesting as the standard Lie product. If so, that is fine.)

Answer (score 6):

For an element $x$ of a ring $R$ with involution $\ast$, the element $x-x^\ast$ is called the skew-trace of $x$. (See e.g. Chapter 2 in the  Herstein's book "Rings with involution"). So $xy-y^\ast x^\ast=xy-(xy)^\ast$ is just the skew-trace of $xy$.

Answer (score 3):

A simple remark:

If $(xy)^*= y^*x^*$ then this is just $xy-(xy)^*$ which is "twice the imaginary part of the product". When $R=\mathbb C$ then this is up to a factor the symplectic form on $\mathbb R^2$ and the determinant of 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \Re x & \Re y \\ \Im x & \Im y
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I'm interested in this "imaginary part" interpretation...as these quantities have arisen in connection with studying the complex group algebra as a *-algebra. I was not aware of this symplectic form.